# Autoselect region for google geochart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

is it possible to autoselect the display region of a google chart api geochart?

I don't know where the cities are, so I can't decide which region to show. Therefore I wonder, if there is a way to let the chart api decide which region to display.

Have a look at this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2mEzV/

All cities are in Europe, so I would like to only show the european continent instead of the whole world.

Can I achieve this with the Google chart api?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, use `region: 155`.

http://jsfiddle.net/2mEzV/71/

See https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#Configuration_Options for all options (scroll down 2 pages).

Comment: with your code it displays Western Europe. This is fine for the provided cities, but I cannot determine where the cities I want to display are located. Therefore I cannot set `region: 155`.
Google does the same I want to achieve on Google Analytics, but I think they can use their Location Database to determine what to show and I have to rely on Google to get the right Geocode for the cities

Comment: Sorry, I had a similar problem. Someone told me to use the undocumented `region:'auto'`, however it doesn't always zoom to the best view. If you specify a `resolution`, then it sometimes fails to load entirely!

Comment: Since you said all countries are in Europe, you can use `region=150` instead.

Comment: auto is not working for me... It always displays the whole world.

Comment: I cannot ensure that all cities are located in Europe. Maybe there is an US city too. That's why I can't set a constant region

Comment: I must have been confused because `All cities are in Europe, so I would like to only show the european continent instead of the whole world.`

Comment: That was ment as an example :)